# Failed to display all the spheres in perspetive projection of 3D animation

Tags: python, animation, opengl, pyglet, psychopy

I have generated an optic flow animation, with spheres (circles) that move towards the viewer in a 3D coordinates space. For some reason, although I define a number of 8 spheres, it never displays all the spheres every time I run the code; sometimes it displays 1, sometimes 4 (like in the gif). It is eventually a random number of spheres from 1 to 8.

My code is available on [Github](https://github.com/Kathia301m/3D-animations-python/blob/master/optic_flow_3D_camera.py)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At perspective projection, the viewing volume is a [frustum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum). So probably the spheres are clipped (not in the frustum) at the sides of the frustum, especially when they are close to the near plane.
Note, most of the stars "leave" the window at its borders, when they come closer to the camera (except the ones, who leave the frustum through the near plane).

Set the initial z-coordinate of the spheres to it's maximum (far plane), for debug reasons:

```py
for sphere in spheres:
    sphere.position.xy = np.random.uniform(-25, 25, size=2)
    #sphere.position.z = np.random.uniform(0.0, -50.0)
    sphere.position.z = 50
```

If you don't "see" all stars at all, then the range for the x and y coordinate ([-25, 25]) is to large.

To compensate the in initial clipping you can scale the x and y component by the distance:

```py
for sphere in spheres:
    sphere.position.xy = np.random.uniform(-25, 25, size=2)
    z = np.random.uniform(0.0, -50.0)
    sphere.position.z = z
    sphere.position.xy[0] *= z/-50
    sphere.position.xy[1] *= z/-50
```

Comment: Many thanks for the clarification!

In Wikipedia, it is mentioned that "Sometimes, the far plane is placed infinitely far away from the camera so all objects within the frustum are drawn regardless of their distance from the camera.". I understand that I should define a far plane that is much further away than 50. I tried 500, and I got glittering dots that are barely visible. Since I need to display the same number of spheres (8 for instance) in each frame, I need to find a way to generate random z-coordinates that are not clipped. Is there a way to go around this constraint?

Comment: *"Since I need to display the same number of spheres [...]"* Why do you need to? Since the spheres are "moving" they will leave the frustum anyway at some point. Anyway, I've extended the answer.

Comment: The number of visible spheres is something I have to control in my experiment in Neuroscience (the brain is sensitive to it apparently). This explains my question yesterday that required adding this condition: ´if sphere.position.z >= camera_z: sphere.position.z = np.random.uniform(camera_z+near_z, camera_z+far_z)´. That way every time a sphere disappears behind the camera, a new one is draw in front of the camera, which keeps a constant number of visible spheres. Strangely, when I add this condition now (after scaling x and y by the distance), it is not keeping the same number of spheres.

Comment: do you mean that instead of `sphere.position.z = np.random.uniform(camera_z+near_z, camera_z+far_z)` , it should be `sphere.position.z = (sphere.position.z-camera_z)/(far_z-camera_z)`. Could you help me understand the reasoning please, thanks alot!

Comment: @Kathia Sorry, I told you a wrong formula. The distance from the camera to the far plane is `far_z` and the distance to the sphere is `sphere.position.z-camera_z`. So the scale factor for x and y has to be `(sphere.position.z-camera_z)/far_z`

Comment: I have tried the formula, but it is producing a strange visual effect. I'd like to share with you the GIF but I probably have to do while asking a new question, as I cannot put the GIF in the comment box. You can find my code here: https://www.codepile.net/pile/7pvd7rGJ

Comment: I created a new question in order to show the visual output https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58917165/keep-constant-number-of-visible-spheres-in-front-of-the-camera-in-3d-animation. Thanks very much for your precious help!