# Keep constant number of visible spheres in front of the camera in 3D animation

Tags: python, animation, opengl, 3d

I created a 3D optic flow animation, where a camera moves towards spheres (as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1d69B.gif) 
). I would like to keep the same number of visible spheres in front of the camera, that way, while the camera moves towards them, and when a sphere is behind the camera, another sphere is drawn in front of the camera. To do so:

- The initial coordinates x,y,z of each sphere is generated:

  ```
   near_z = -10.0;
   far_z = -50.0;
   nSpheres = 8;

  for sphere in spheres:
      sphere.position.xy = np.random.uniform(-25, 25, size=2)
      z = np.random.uniform(near_z, far_z)

      sphere.position.z = z
      sphere.position.x *= z/far_z
      sphere.position.y *= z/far_z
  ```
- Then within the loop that creates the animation and updates the position, there is a condition that keeps a constant number of spheres in front of the camera: every time one disappears, it should calculate the coordinates of a new one in front of the camera.

  ```
  while 1:


   with shader:

     # Move the camera towards the spheres
     camera_z -= .6

     transformations['view_matrix'] = get_view_matrix(z=camera_z)
     transformations.send()


     for sphere in spheres:
         sphere.draw()

      # If a sphere is behind a camera, generate new sphere coordinates, with the z from the camera to z_far.This way we keep a constant number of visible spheres.

         if sphere.position.z >= camera_z:

           sphere.position.z = np.random.uniform(camera_z+near_z, camera_z+far_z)
           sphere.position.x = np.random.uniform((sphere.position.z-camera_z)/far_z)
           sphere.position.y = np.random.uniform((sphere.position.z-camera_z)/far_z)
  ```

As you can see in the GIF below, there seem to be 2 phases:

First, the spheres are randomly and uniformly distributed in the screen, and disappear behind the camera when it passes by. But no new sphere is created when one disappears (the condition in the loop above doesn't seem to work in the beginning).

Then starts a series of spheres appearing when another disappears (due to the condition in the loop) but the new spheres are always coming from the centre and following the same path. Therefore, they are not generated randomly and distributed uniformly in the screen.

[image]

For the sake of clarity, you can find my code [here](https://www.codepile.net/pile/7pvd7rGJ)

Comment: In the last three lines of the second code sample, just assume that "sphere.position.z = camera_z+far_z" (biggest possible absolute value) and calculate the "uniform" parameter for the next two lines.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I think the problem lies in the `sphere.position.xy` in the second code sample. Changing `sphere.position.z` to `camera_z+far_z` results in the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you recreate the spheres, the you've to generate random x and y coordinates the initial range from -25.0 to 25.0. But you've to scale the coordinates by the relative distance to the camera (`z/far_z`):

```py
if sphere.position.z >= camera_z:

    z_abs = np.random.uniform(camera_z+near_z, camera_z+far_z) 
    sphere.position.z = z_abs 
    sphere.position.x = np.random.uniform(-25, 25) * (z_abs-camera_z)/far_z
    sphere.position.y = np.random.uniform(-25, 25) * (z_abs-camera_z)/far_z
```

respectively

```py
if sphere.position.z >= camera_z:

    z_rel = np.random.uniform(near_z, far_z) 
    sphere.position.z = z_rel + camera_z
    sphere.position.x = np.random.uniform(-25, 25) * z_rel/far_z
    sphere.position.y = np.random.uniform(-25, 25) * z_rel/far_z
```

---

Of course this won't solve your issue completely. The condition `sphere.position.z >= camera_z` handles the spheres which leave the view volume through the near plane. At perspective projection the view volume is a [Frustum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum). There are spheres which leave the view at the sides of the frustum (at the sides of the window).
To handel this you'll need a 2nd condition and you've to take into account the maximum distance of a sphere to the center of the view:

```py
max_dist   = max(abs(sphere.position.x), abs(sphere.position.y))
limit_dist = 25 * abs((sphere.position.z-camera_z) / far_z)

if sphere.position.z >= camera_z or max_dist > limit_dist:

    # [...]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Although it seems perfectly logical, and I was convinced this would work, it still doesn't keep the same number of spheres. I uploaded the GIF here [link] (https://imgur.com/3IgeIIv). The first phase shows the right number of spheres (4) but the condition in the loop isn't applied. The second phase shows a generation of spheres but it doesn't show all the spheres (4). I would expect that the condition should apply from the beginning.

Comment: Doesn't the x y rescaling by the distance (*z/z_far) compensate the clipping? The first block sample succeeded in generating 4 visible spheres that are not clipped. That explains that the video starts with 4 spheres. After the camera passes the 4 spheres, we observe 1 sphere or 2 appearings. I would assume that `* (z_abs-camera_z)/far_z` prevents the clipping of the spheres.

Comment: @Kathia I've extended the answer.

Comment: I encountered the same issue with a different animation, that has a different movement pattern, and tried to use the same logic as your answer here. I'd be very grateful if you could help me with it [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/q/60435851/7951365)