# Keep constant number of visible circles in 3D animation

Tags: python, animation, opengl, 3d

I have created a 3D animation with a perspective projection of white circles moving randomly in a fake 3D space projected on a 2D computer screen (GIF 1).

[image]

Since I need to keep the same number of visible circles, every time a circle disappears from the frame, I have to create a new visible one within the frame. To do so, I have written this piece of code:

- First I created initial coordinates and the two angles of movements (spherical coordinates):

  ```
  for circle in circles:

      circle.position.xy = np.random.uniform(-25, 25, size=2)
      z = np.random.uniform(near_z, far_z)

      circle.position.z = z
      circle.position.x *= z/-50
      circle.position.y *= z/-50

      circle.theta_deg = np.random.rand(1) * 360
      circle.phi_deg = np.random.rand(1) * 360

      theta_rad = circle.theta_deg * np.pi / 180
      phi_rad = circle.phi_deg* np.pi / 180


      circle.dx = speed * np.sin(-phi_rad - theta_rad) / frameRate
      circle.dy = -speed * np.cos(phi_rad + theta_rad) / frameRate
      circle.dz = -speed * np.cos(theta_rad) / frameRate
  ```

  - Then, in the loop that plays the animation, and updates the position of each circle, I have put this condition following the same answer that was provided to the same kind of issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58917165/keep-constant-number-of-visible-spheres-in-front-of-the-camera-in-3d-animation):

    ```
    max_dist = max(abs(circle.position.x),abs(circle.position.y))
    limit_dist = 25 * abs((circle.position.z-near_z) / far_z)

    z_rel = np.random.uniform(near_z,far_z)

    if max_dist > limit_dist: 
        circle.position.x = np.random.uniform(-25, 25) * z_rel/far_z
        circle.position.y = np.random.uniform(-25, 25) * z_rel/far_z
    ```

I got a weird result as shown in GIF 2

[image]

What is wrong with my condition and how can I detect a circle that disappears from the frame and recreate one inside the frame?

Following the suggestion of @Fabian N. (answer below), I have reset the z-coordinates along with the x and y coordinates as follows:

```
    max_dist   = max(abs(circle.position.x), abs(circle.position.y))        # Find maximum distance of a circle to the center of the view:
    limit_dist = 25 * abs((circle.position.z-near_z) / far_z)


    if circle.position.z <= near_z or max_dist > limit_dist:

        z_rel = np.random.uniform(near_z,far_z) 
        circle.position.z = z_rel + near_z

        circle.position.x = np.random.uniform(-25, 25) * z_rel/far_z
        circle.position.y = np.random.uniform(-25, 25) * z_rel/far_z
```

And I got this result:
[image]

Comment: What is `circle.position.xy`?

Comment: @ScottHunter it is the (x,y) coordinates of each circle.

Comment: Just confirming that the assignment to `position.xy` was a typo when posting your code here, and was not in the actual code being executed?

Comment: @ScottHunter if you are referring to the line `circle.position.xy = np.random.uniform(-25, 25, size=2)` in the first block, it is not a typo.

Comment: No, I'm referring to the one at the bottom that you replaced with `position.x` in your edit.

Comment: Ah indeed, that was a typo!

Comment: writing as a comment since not sure how you try to achieve. First thing that came to my mind is using your camera, define the frustum. whenever your sphere is out of frustrum, randomly generate a new one, and give direction.

Comment: @sariug yes, it was done at the beginning of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you posted I can only see two points of interest without actually running it 
<sup>(could you add some glue code around the code you posted to make it runnable as a standalone example?)</sup>

1. You are only resetting the x and y position in the if condition, you need to reset z too, otherwise, they will fly behind the camera or vanish in the distance
2. the if-condition from the question you linked has another part: `sphere.position.z >= camera_z` which would translate for your code into `circle.position.z <= near_z` to actually detect spheres flying behind the camera

Both can't really explain what's happening in your second gif...

---

On second thought: the jumping circles in gif 2 could just be circles that get instantly reset each frame because they aren't properly reset as their z-coordinate stays the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input! I have taken your input into account and reset the z coordinates as suggested. You can find the new lines of code/changes as well as the video that resulted from it in my updated question above. For some reason, it does not work...

Answer (score 0):

In the code that you've added, you are resetting the z parameter differently than the way you initialized it.

In the first part of your code, you use

```
z = np.random.uniform(near_z, far_z)
circle.position.z = z
circle.position.x *= z/-50
circle.position.y *= z/-50
```

while in the for loop you use

```
z_rel = np.random.uniform(near_z,far_z)
circle.position.z = z_rel + near_z
circle.position.x = np.random.uniform(-25, 25) * z_rel/far_z
circle.position.y = np.random.uniform(-25, 25) * z_rel/far_z
```

These do not seem to be equivalent. Perhaps you should use the same parameters for both.

You should also check the way that you update your x and y positions, especially your parameters dx and dy, as these may be getting so big that your circles fly out of the screen immediately

Comment: I am sure I understand the message, for instance, what are the parameters you are referring to? the circle positions inside the loop have different values because the goal is to make the circle move frame by frame. I've already checked the x and y position updates and put the results in my question to get help from the community. Do you have any suggestion to how I could check better the updates or what parameters I have to change?

Comment: Sorry if that was unclear.
The code you copied to reset the z position was used for a camera moving towards the spheres, although it doesn't seem that this is your goal (unless I am mistaken in which case the code is probably correct). 
In your IF condition, you should probably reset the z position the same way that you initialized it